# How to create cron job to run shell script every minute

Tags: bash, cron

I wan to create cron job that runs a shell script every minute I've tried editing contrab -e with:

```
1 * * * * sh ~/test.sh
```

to no avail

Comment: General rule of thumb: always use complete paths in a crontab. eg `/bin/sh /root/test.sh` or `/bin/sh /home/foo/test.sh`

Comment: Yeah, don't use `~` either. What does "to no avail" mean? Please provide unexpected output/results or error messages.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using: https://crontab.guru/

This is a really insightful way to create and understand cron jobs.

This should trigger every minute.  However, when a cron runs it can run as a different user and that script location might be different.  Adding a log file might help you track down what is going on.

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/user/test.sh >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Comment: If his cronjob is running as a non-privileged user, he may not have write permission to /var/log/.

Comment: not getting anything written to logs and I'm using root user

Comment: @pythonic12 when you enter and exit `crontab -e` do you see a message that says you have mail?